# Serving image assets from S3 with ember-cli-deploy Lightning method

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm trying to deploy an Ember CLI app using ember-cli-deploy and the 'lightning' deployment method (http://ember-cli-deploy.com/docs/v0.6.x/the-lightning-strategy/).

I've got a redis server to serve my index.html file. I've got my assets uploaded to S3. However my image assets don't seem to be loading properly.

In ember-cli-build.js I have:

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  fingerprint: {
    prepend: '//path-to-my-S3-bucket/'
  }
});
```

but for some reason images are still being served from the redis server IP. I am getting errors like "Failed to load http://redis-server-url/my-image.jpg". Javascript and CSS files are working fine from S3.

Have I missed something here? Is there another step to this configuration?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would confirm that fingerprinting is enabled. It is only enabled for 'production' builds by default. You should see an md5 checksum appended to your asset file names. For example, `my-image.jpg` should be something like `my-image-9c2cbd818d09a4a742406c6cb8219b3b.jpg`

You can override the default behavior by passing the `enabled` option:

```
var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
  fingerprint: {
    enabled: true,
    prepend: '//path-to-my-S3-bucket/'
  }
});
```

Comment: That sounds like this may be the cause of the problem that the OP is experiencing. If OP is trying to deploy to a different environment than production please be aware of the fact that one should not do that based on the passed environment in ember-cli-build.js but on the the DEPLOY_TARGET environment variable set by ember-cli-deploy (which might be the cause for this unexpected behaviour that the OP is describing) See http://blog.firstiwaslike.com/staging-environments-with-ember-cli-deploy/ for more background